# Binding Click function for one element to the click function of another

Tags: jquery, click

I have a click function on the following element:

```
$('#make article > a, #latestInner article > a').click(function (e) {...});
```

Now I want to bind the clicking of the above to the following:

```
$('#make article h4 a, #latestInner article h4 a, #models article h4 a').click(function (e) {...});
```

so that clicking on:

```
#make article > a, #latestInner article > a
```

will be as if I have clicked on:

```
#make article h4 a, #latestInner article h4 a, #models article h4 a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `trigger()` will do that :

```
$('#make article > a, #latestInner article > a').click(function() {
    $('#make, #latestInner, #models').find('article h4 a').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#make article > a, #latestInner article > a').click(function (e) {    
 ("#make article h4 a").trigger('click');    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#make article > a, #latestInner article > a').click(function (e) {
    $('#make article h4 a').click();
    $('#latestInner article h4 a').click();
    $('#models article h4 a').click();
});

$('#make article h4 a, #latestInner article h4 a, #models article h4 a').click(function (e) {...});
```

Hope it helps :)